# Is there a way in Azure DevOps to group by the first sublayer of Area Paths?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

My current requirement is to create charts out of queries in Azure DevOps (for ex. pie charts) that visualize certain work items and group by the Area Path of the work items. However, the grouping in the chart should only consider the first sublayer. So for instance, it should only consider root-path/x instead of root-path/x/y and root-path/x/z individually.

The only solution I could think of so far was to consider the *Team*-field instead of the *Area Path*-field as a team should be associated with every subpath, but apparently, teams aren't associated with work items and the *Team*-fields in the result of my queries remain empty.

Is there an other solution or "workaround" to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and tried other Chart extensions, but none of them can meet your demand.

When selecting "**Group by Area Path**", they always list all the area paths of the work items from the selected queries.

I also checked '**`Project configuration`**' and '**`Team configuration`**' on '**Project Settings**', but did not find any option can affect this.

Looks like, we currently have no any available solution or workaround that can group work items by only the first sub-paths of the root area path on the Chart for work items.

Maybe you can try to develop a custom Chart extension following your demand.